# Error running Tensorflow Object Detection with custom dataset

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I've been trying to use tensorflow's object detection api for a school project and I've managed to follow their instructions in the documentation, but I'm getting this error I can't find anywhere online.
This is the output in the console:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x7f118aa30e18>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:80: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(...)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py:1165: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py:1218: calling squeeze (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with squeeze_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the `axis` argument instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:148: batch_and_drop_remainder (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.batching) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.batch(..., drop_remainder=True)`.
2018-12-28 19:39:31.314235: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:108] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2018-12-28 19:39:32.354316: E tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.cc:108] Write failed because file could not be opened.
2018-12-28 19:39:33.177681: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-12-28 19:39:33.246316: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-12-28 19:39:33.246780: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 960M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.176
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 3.95GiB freeMemory: 3.59GiB
2018-12-28 19:39:33.246813: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-12-28 19:39:33.798306: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-12-28 19:39:33.798331: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2018-12-28 19:39:33.798337: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2018-12-28 19:39:33.798491: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3310 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 109, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 105, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 610, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 711, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1241, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1468, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    log_step_count_steps=log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 504, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 921, in __init__
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 643, in __init__
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1107, in __init__
    _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._create_session())
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1112, in _create_session
    return self._sess_creator.create_session()
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 807, in create_session
    hook.after_create_session(self.tf_sess, self.coord)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 559, in after_create_session
    "graph.pbtxt")
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_io.py", line 71, in write_graph
    text_format.MessageToString(graph_def))
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 434, in atomic_write_string_to_file
    write_string_to_file(temp_pathname, contents)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 314, in write_string_to_file
    f.write(file_content)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 108, in write
    self._prewrite_check()
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 94, in _prewrite_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), compat.as_bytes(self.__mode), status)
  File "/home/pipas/.pyenv/versions/vcom/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: /home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/data/labels.pbtxt/graph.pbtxt.tmp13ac703bc82a469eaec2c658091efd80; Not a directory
```

This is what I'm running

```
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=/home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/models/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline.config
MODEL_DIR=/home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/data/labels.pbtxt
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=5000
SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1
python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=$SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES \
    --alsolog
```

and here is the pipeline.config file

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 5
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v1"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.99999989895e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.0299999993294
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.999700009823
          center: true
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000475
          train: true
        }
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.99999989895e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.0299999993294
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.999700009823
            center: true
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000475
            train: true
          }
        }
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.800000011921
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.20000000298
        max_scale: 0.949999988079
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.333299994469
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.300000011921
        iou_threshold: 0.600000023842
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.990000009537
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 24
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.00400000018999
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.949999988079
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.899999976158
      decay: 0.899999976158
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/models/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 200000
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/data/labels.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/data/porto_train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 8000
  max_evals: 10
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/data/labels.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/data/porto_val.record"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have MODEL_DIR pointing to your label file, when it should be pointing to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `fine_tune_checkpoint` with below line

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/pipas/School/tensorflow-models/research/porto-recognition/models/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
```